# How to change text for a Button with jQuery in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I tried this code on jQuery to change the `btn` text when I click on a `span` that opens a modal to add a `ShipWay`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#spanOpen").click(function () {
        $("#fulldiv").fadeIn(1000);
        $('#titleModal').text('הוספת שלוחה');
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_btnAddShip").prop('value', 'הוסף');
        $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtShipName').val('');
        $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtShipPrice').val('');
        $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtShipStart').val('');
        $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtShipEnd').val('');
        $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtShipPremium').val('No');

    });
    $(".close").click(function () {
        $("#fulldiv").fadeOut(500);
    });
});

function UpdateClick(btn)
{
    $("#fulldiv").fadeIn(1000);
    var row = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
    var rowIndex = row.rowIndex - 1;
    $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtShipName').val(row.cells[6].innerHTML);
    $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtShipPrice').val(row.cells[5].innerHTML);
    $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtShipStart').val(row.cells[4].innerHTML);
    $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtShipEnd').val(row.cells[3].innerHTML);
    $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtShipPremium').val(row.cells[2].innerHTML);
    $('#titleModal').text('עדכן שלוחה');
    $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_btnAddShip").prop('value', 'עדכן');
    return false;
}
```

This is the button I use in my html for Add/Update the row:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnAddShip" runat="server" ValidationGroup="AddShip" Text="" 
 CssClass="btn" OnClick="btnAddShip_Click" />
```

When I tried to check his text in the code behind he said that he have nothing like = "".

This is my code in the C# 
In the first if I want to ask if the text of the button is Add 
and if not it will be Update in the else 
the code go for WebService and to Xml
I tried the code he works well I just need that if will work perfect
because I don't want to create another button

```
ElectricWSL.Ship ship = new ElectricWSL.Ship();
ship.ShipName = txtShipName.Text.Trim();
ship.ShipPremium = txtShipPremium.Text.Trim();
ship.ShipPrice = double.Parse(txtShipPrice.Text);
ship.ShipStartTime = txtShipStart.Text.Trim();
ship.ShipEndTime = txtShipEnd.Text.Trim();
if (btnAddShip.Text == "הוסף")
{
    ws.WSLAddShip(ship);
    ShowXMLGrid();
}
else
{

    int rowIndex = GetRow(txtShipName.Text);
    ws.WSLUpdateShip(ship, rowIndex);
    ShowXMLGrid();
}
```

Comment: Even if you change the text with jQuery. When you do a PostBack it's original state will be restored.

Comment: I think you may want to edit this as without the punctuation the question is quite hard to follow. Also I assume the last code block is the function btnAddShip_Click, and excuse my ignorance, but I don't know if the id of the button in the jquery should be #btn_addShip... Does the button text get correctly set to Add on the webform?
 In answer to your question it sounds like if it ="" in c# it's broken, but if it works for you then it works. The logic is okay, although you don't handle errors.

Comment: If English is not your main language, please at least use a spell checker.

Answer (score 0):

Answering one of your point in details ***when i tried to check his text in the code behind it contains like =""***

Button text is empty in code because

```
<asp:Button ID="btnAddShip" runat="server" ValidationGroup="AddShip" Text="" 
        CssClass="btn" OnClick="btnAddShip_Click" />
```

Add some text to it like

```
<asp:Button ID="btnAddShip" runat="server" ValidationGroup="AddShip" Text="Add" 
        CssClass="btn" OnClick="btnAddShip_Click" />
```

And get it in code behind like

```
if (btnAddShip.Text == "Add")
{
    ws.WSLAddShip(ship);
    ShowXMLGrid();
}
else
{

    int rowIndex = GetRow(txtShipName.Text);
    ws.WSLUpdateShip(ship, rowIndex);
    ShowXMLGrid();
}
```

Comment: He tries to do this in jquery, does asp webforms add ContentPlaceHolder1_ to ids?

Comment: he said `when i tried to check his text in the code bheind he said that he have nothing like =""`